# How to draw a dashed line with *-mark + error marks + a line in foreground in the same plot with pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

I create a plot with pgfplots with the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}

\begin{filecontents}{ExampleData.txt}
xValue1 yValue1 Deltay1
-0.405  0       0
-0.355  0       0
-0.305  1       1
-0.245  2       1.41
-0.195  117     10.82
-0.155  111     10.54
-0.105  132     11.49
-0.055  142     11.92
-0.005  122     11.05
0.045   109     10.44
0.095   135     11.62
0.145   131     11.45
0.195   110     10.49
0.245   42      6.48
0.295   0       0
0.345   0       0
0.395   0       0
0.445   0       0
0.495   0       0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
%clip mode=individual,
xmin=-0.5,xmax=0.5,ymin=0,ymax=150, 
enlargelimits=false,
axis on top=true,
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$]
\addplot[dashed,
color=blue,
thick,
%only marks,
mark=*,
/pgfplots/error bars/.cd,
    x dir=none,
    y dir=both,
    y explicit,
    error bar style={color=blue,solid}] 
table [
x=xValue1,
y=yValue1,
y error=Deltay1] {ExampleData.txt};
\draw[thick, <->] (axis cs:-0.195,117) -- (axis cs:0.195,117);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output

[image: Plot with marked problems]

is almost what I want to have, but there are some things I am not able to improve by myself:

If I use a dashed line instead of a solid one, the markers are not a round disk anymore. How can I avoid this?

I want to have the arrow in the foreground. I thought I can use `clip mode=individual` for that. But then sometimes my error bars are being plotted outside of my axes. How can I have my arrow in the foreground without creating such an effect?

I would be very happy about some help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you can play with the layers to get different effects such as clipping the markers or leaving on the axis lines etc.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}

\begin{filecontents}{ExampleData.txt}
xValue1 yValue1 Deltay1
-0.405  0       0
-0.355  0       0
-0.305  1       1
-0.245  2       1.41
-0.195  117     10.82
-0.155  111     10.54
-0.105  132     11.49
-0.055  142     11.92
-0.005  122     11.05
0.045   109     10.44
0.095   135     11.62
0.145   131     11.45
0.195   110     10.49
0.245   42      6.48
0.295   0       0
0.345   0       0
0.395   0       0
0.445   0       0
0.495   0       0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[set layers,
xmin=-0.5,xmax=0.5,ymin=0,ymax=150, 
enlargelimits=false,
axis on top=true,
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$]
\addplot[dashed,
color=blue,
thick,
mark=*,
mark options={thin,solid}, %<--- Change
mark layer=like plot,      %<--- Change
/pgfplots/error bars/.cd,
    x dir=none,
    y dir=both,
    y explicit,
    error bar style={color=blue,solid}] 
table [
x=xValue1,
y=yValue1,
y error=Deltay1] {ExampleData.txt};
\draw[thick, <->,on layer=axis foreground] (axis cs:-0.195,117) -- (axis cs:0.195,117);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the bad image cropping.

Comment: Ah, much better!

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! You have solved all my problems in a very easy way! Thanks again!