# dashed line in pgfplots legend results in incomplete marks

Tags: pgfplots, legend

When defining the pgfplots legend entries myself, I have a problem when using dashed lines in combination with marks. The mark is also dashed (or dotted, etc.), just as the accompanying line is. Is there a way of making sure that marks are drawn completely when using dashed/dotted/etc. lines?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    legend pos=south east,
    legend entries={Entry 1,Entry 2,Entry 3}
    ]
    \addlegendimage{blue,only marks,mark=oplus}
    \addlegendimage{blue,dashed,no marks}
    \addlegendimage{blue,dashed,mark=oplus}
    \addplot+[black,no marks,domain=0:10]
    {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: use this: `\addlegendimage{blue,dashed,mark=oplus,mark options=solid}`

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84287/how-to-draw-a-dashed-line-with-mark-error-marks-a-line-in-foreground-in-th

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
\addlegendimage{blue,dashed,mark=oplus,mark options=solid}
```

Comment: sorry for the late answer - have been in holidays.